# how to change the locale language on SAS?

Tags: sas

the system options shows other than english on the SAS product, due to which some of the properties and also the help manual is not in english, how is it possible to change it? or do I have to install the SAS again?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you installed the correct language(s), it's possible to run SAS in different languages.  However, if you only installed one language, it will be sufficiently complicated that I would recommend an update installation (which is not a full reinstall).

[This SAS technical support note](http://support.sas.com/kb/18/639.html) covers this in some detail; it also recommends an update installation if you didn't install the language originally.

What you can do is look at the SASFoundation folder in your install, usually one more folder deep (the version), and then look at the `nls` folder.  `nls` refers to language support, and it should have one folder for each language installed, including Unicode support and DBCS support.  `\nls\en` will exist if you installed English.

If that's the case, you can edit your `sasv9.cfg` to point to the config file you want to use - ie, the \nls\en config file.  It probably points to whatever you currently are running.

You also can on the fly run one or the other simply by including in the shortcut or launch program the `-config` option pointing to the config file you want.